# Google Glass and Wearable Data Layer API

Tags: android, google-glass, wear-os, data-transfer, android-wear-data-api

I am trying to make a connection between my companion app and glass app. I am trying to use the data-layer api for this purpose. I wanted to avoid any bluetooth and socket programming for this purpose.
Initially, i am trying to send data from phone to glass. Phone is able to send the data. On glass, i have the wearable listener service, which works fine on android watches and phone, but when i used it on glass, i got the following warning message :

> 12-29 12:56:11.343: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(6041): Calling package com.example.glassware signature (release key) invalid on Glass.

I have no idea how to go about it. Any ideas? 
Is there any other way, i can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that you are using release key which is used in the development of apps on watch (or some other wearable) which is eventually not compatible with the Glass development. Please make sure your code follows the directory architecture provided in this [Github code](https://github.com/googleglass/). Also you have right level of permissions in your manifest. If your app is using some services they are declared in there. Last but not the lease make sure you have the latest version of the Google Play Services imported in your app project and there are no compatibility issues.

Hope this would help!!!

Comment: Yeah, the thing is, Glass doesn't support the GoogleApIServices yet .. So, i can't use WearableListenerService on glass.. Hopefully, google will take care of this, soon ..

Comment: Yes for now there are no WearableListererService interface available for implementing a connection between Glass and phone through GoogleServiceapi. If you want to establish a connection through Bluetooth here is one example (https://github.com/NathanielWaggoner/GoogleGlassBlutooth) to establish connection.